# Search a column and return lowest grade

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset that I want to search for the `lowest` and `highest` school grade which contains `PK,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12`. 
I want to add lowest and highest as its own columns to the dataframe.

**Input data:**

```
    Name               Grades_Offered_All       Student_Count_Total
    A                      PK,K,1,2,3,4,5           415
    B                      PK,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8     241
    C                      PK,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8     346
    D                      K,1,2                    91
    E                      PK,K,1,2,3               248
```

**Expected output:**

```
    Lowest
    A = PK
    B = PK
    C = PK
    D = K
    E = PK

    Highest
    A = 5
    B = 8
    C = 8
    D = 2
    E = 3
```

Comment: If the data is as shown, then you just have to look for an alphanumeric sequence before the first comma, and an alphanumeric sequence following the last comma.

Comment: for pandas `.25.0` version: `df.assign(k=df.Grades_Offered_All.str.split(',')).explode('k').groupby('Name')['k'].agg(['first','last'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['Lowest'] = df['Grades_Offered_All'].str.split(",").str[0]
df['Highest'] = df['Grades_Offered_All'].str.split(",").str[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.extract` with named groups

```
df.Grades_Offered_All.str.extract(r'(?P<Lowest>[^,]+).+(?P<Highest>[^,]+)')

Out[480]:
  Lowest Highest
0     PK       5
1     PK       8
2     PK       8
3      K       2
4     PK       3
```

If you need to have `A, B, C...` as in your desired output, just do as follows:

```
(df.Name.values[:,None] + ' = ' 
        + df.Grades_Offered_All.str.extract(r'(?P<Lowest>[^,]+).+(?P<Highest>[^,]+)'))

Out[497]:
   Lowest Highest
0  A = PK   A = 5
1  B = PK   B = 8
2  C = PK   C = 8
3   D = K   D = 2
4  E = PK   E = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

use a lambda:

```
df['Lowest'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Name+" = "+x.Grades_Offered_All.split(",")[0], axis=1)

df['Highest'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Name+" = "+x.Grades_Offered_All.split(",")[-1], axis=1)
```

result:

```
        Name    Grades_Offered_All       Student_Count_Total    Highest Lowest
    0   A       PK,K,1,2,3,4,5           415                    A = 5   A = PK
    1   B       PK,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8     241                    B = 8   B = PK
    2   C       PK,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8     346                    C = 8   C = PK
    3   D       K,1,2                    91                     D = 2   D = K
    4   E       PK,K,1,2,3               248                    E = 3   E = PK
```

if you only want Highest and Lowest as you dataframe simply do: `df=df[['Highest','Lowest']]`